# Finding a regex to match all the cases in background image url

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to find a regex that will be able to treat 3 cases that i have in html.

For instance,

1. background-image: url(https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture.png); background-size: 100%...
2. background-image: url("https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture(1_2)_pic(23).png")
3. background-image: url(https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture)

In this 3 cases , i want to extract the 3 urls:

1. https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture.png
2. https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture(1_2)_pic(23).png
3. https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture

I created a regex that is able to extract only the first two. Unfortunately, cannot think of the regex that will be able to get the third case(url path without extension) also inside that one regex.

what i came up with so far:

```
/background(?:-image|):[\s]*url[(][\"']?(https?:\/\/[^’\”]+[.](?:gif|png))[‘\”]?/g
```

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: in which language you are trying to do that? For the last case, maybe you could search for the `)` which is the end of the string with the `$` ?

Answer (score 2):

This regex pattern treats the nested parentheses as an optional repeated group between the parentheses of the `url()`.

```
background-image:\s*url\(['"]?((?:\S*?\(\S*?\))*\S*?)['"]?\)
```

**Javascript snippet:**

```js
const text = `background-image: url(https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture.png); background-size: 100%...
background-image: url("https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture(1_2)_pic(23).png")
background-image: url(https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture)
`;
let re = /background-image:\s*url\(['"]?((?:\S*?\(\S*?\))*\S*?)['"]?\)/g;
let arr = [...text.matchAll(re)].map(x=>x[1]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thank you very much! Can you please explain it a bit? @LukStorms

Comment: It's just that this `((?:\S*?\(\S*?\))*` looks for stuff within parentheses. The `\S` is for anything that's not a whitespace, which a normalized url shouldn't have.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
background-image:\s*url\((['"]?)(\S*?)\1\)
```

- `background-image:\s*` Match literally followed by optional whitespace chars
- `url\(` Match `url(`
- `(['"]?)` Capture **group 1**, optionally match either `'` or `"`
- `(\S*?)` Capture **group 2**, match optional non whitespace characters as least as possible
- `\1` Backreference to match the same that is in capture group 1
- `\)` Match `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7YuSgK/1)

The url is in capture group 2. An example using JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /background-image:\s*url\((['"]?)(\S*?)\1\)/g;
const str = `background-image: url(https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture.png); background-size: 100%...
background-image: url("https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture(1_2)_pic(23).png")
background-image: url(https://www.aaa.com/xxx/picture)`;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[2]));
```